# Java code for creating paths

Tags: java

Trying to code this in java. Please suggest any algorithm that would work for this scenario.
 The input is:

```
Col A   Col B
A       B
A       C
B       D
C       A
C       B
C       E
D       A
D       B
E       A
```

I am trying to make combinations such as Output:

```
A   B   D   A       
A   C   A           
A   C   B   D   A   
A   C   E   A       
B   D   B           
C   A   B   D   A   C
C   A   C           
C   B   D   A   C   
C   E   A   C

|
|
|
```

and so on. 
The output should have the starting point and ending point as the same.

Another way of looking at it is, you are starting from a node A and you have to get back to node A, so your path would be from A to B then B to D(because from B you can only go to one node i.e. D), then D to A. So, col A and Col B gives you the possible paths, for example from A you can only go to B and C, and not D and E. I hope this helps.
Also, is there any way to restrict the no. of nodes for a solution ?

Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: This seems like a directed graph to me.  Do you know what they are from a math standpoint, and do you understand how to implement one in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion, and as you recurse through the data you need to mark where you have visited so that you do not walk the same path infinitely,

Answer (score 0):

From your data, you have a collection of five distinct nodes - A, B, C, D, and E.

If we combine them together, then we get a mapping of what relates to what:

```
A:  [B, C]
B:  [D]
C:  [B, E]
D:  [A, B]
E:  [A]
```

The above represents a [sparse graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph#Sparse_and_tight_graphs).  A node doesn't directly connect back to itself from another node, except for B->D->B.

Here's a flow process of how I'd approach it.

- Use a `Map<String, List<String>` for the primary node I reach, and the edges that this node is connected to.
- Select a starting node, *a*.  Place its links into a stack.
- Check to see if the end node is the same as the start.

  - If it is, you're done - pop the elements from the stack and get your path.
  - If it isn't, pop the first element from the stack and push its links into the stack.  Repeat from the check.
- If there is nothing to pop, then there is no path from *a* to *a*.

This style of traversal is a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).  You're going deeper into the graph until you reach either your path or exhaust your options.

Comment: Also to your observation that "The above represents a sparse graph. A node doesn't directly connect back to itself from another node, except for B->D->B.", there two more paths which directly connect back to itself ACA and CAC.

Comment: Makoto: If i use this algorithm, is there a way to restrict the solution to a specific no. of nodes. So I don't want the algorithm to explore the paths where the no. of nodes exceeds by 6. Please advice.

Comment: Algorithm Depth Limited Search ?